# laravel error when deployed on shared host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy my app on a shared host.  I followed the instructions on this page:

http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

I believe it is set up ok, however, I get the following error:

> ErrorException
>   include(app/views/layouts/question.blade.php) [href='function.include'>function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or >directory (View: /home/d****/*****/app/views/questionairres/create.blade.php)

I did check and the file exists in this exact location.  Does anybody have any idea why this error may be coming up?  Any ideas on how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when the file exists, but it's not readable by the webserver, because it might not have the proper permissions to read the script file:

```
-rw-rw----  1 root root         182 Jan 16 18:24 question.blade.php
```

So you need to make it be

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root         182 Jan 16 18:24 question.blade.php
```

using

```
chmod +r question.blade.php
```

or

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root www-data     182 Jan 16 18:24 question.blade.php
```

by

```
chown root:www-data question.blade.php
```

And the user `www-data` in some distros might have another name: httpd, apache...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure that I understand.  What will I be editing exactly?

Comment: File permissions. If you're not on a Unix, Linux or Mac OS server, you have to check the permissions for your kind of server. Just edited to clarify.

Comment: Ok.  I'm actually on a shared server.  Would I have to speak to support in order to access this?

Comment: How did you uploaded your files?

Comment: You can change the permissions using Filezilla itself: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-.html

Comment: It has it set to the following for question.blade.php: Owner: read, write; group: read; public: read  Shouldn't that be ok?

Comment: Yeah, but check if folders have the executable bit set, because listing folders is the executable bit.

Comment: Yeah, they are all set to executable.

Comment: Well, now you have some information to talk to your support. :)